# How to create users and groups migrations in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, rbac

So I've got an API built in Django with Django Rest Framework and I now want to add a role based access control to it. For this I found the [django-rest-framework-roles extension](https://github.com/computer-lab/django-rest-framework-roles). I've got it installed, but I'm not really familiar with the usual authentication system in Django. It says I need to define the groups in the settings as

```
ROLE_GROUPS = [group.name.lower() for group in Group.objects.all()]
```

So I need the `Group` model and of course also the `User` model. As far as I understand, these are standard models. However, I don't have any tables in my DB for them. So I need a migration for it, but I'm unsure how I can do that.

I guess it should be really easy, but even on [the relevant pages in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/) I don't see any mention on how to add these models to my Django installation.

Could anybody enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `settings.py` you have something like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.auth",
    ...
]
```

That app has the Group and User models(included django app), so the first thing that you will do after config the database is migrate with this command`./manage.py migrate`, after migrate you can use importing them like this: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group`

Answer (score 2):

The standard `User` model in django has the table name `auth_user`.

The standard `Group` model has the table name of `auth_group`.

The database tables themselves are created once you have ran your first migration script after starting your project.

This is done from the command line with:

`$ python manage.py migrate`